# Formula to iterate through complex JSON string, script erroring after second recursion

Tags: powershell

I have a function I was trying to build in PowerShell to explore an unknown JSON structure and am having trouble with the recursion failing after the second run.

Here is my code:

```
#Example string taken randomly from https://hackersandslackers.com/extract-data-from-complex-json-python/
$TestJson = @"
{
  "destination_addresses": [
    "Philadelphia, PA, USA"
  ],
  "origin_addresses": [
    "New York, NY, USA"
  ],
  "rows": [{
    "elements": [{
      "distance": {
        "text": "94.6 mi",
        "value": 152193
      },
      "duration": {
        "text": "1 hour 44 mins",
        "value": 6227
      },
      "status": "OK"
    }]
  }],
  "status": "OK"
}
"@
$TestObj = ConvertFrom-Json $TestJson


Function Map-NestedPSObj {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        $Obj,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        $Iteration=0
    )
    Begin {
        #Get type of object passed
        $ObjTypeName = (($Obj).GetType()).Name
        #Create next iteration #, to pass to recursive call
        $NextIteration = $Iteration+1
    }
    Process {
        #Switch statement to process according to which obj type was passed to script
        Switch ($ObjTypeName)
        {
        #Run if $obj is a PSCustomObject
        "PSCustomObject" {
            #Loop through NoteProperties
            foreach($rootProperty in @($Obj.psobject.properties | where-object {$_.MemberType -eq "NoteProperty"}) )
            {
                #Get name of current NoteProperty
                $PropertyName = $rootProperty.Name
                #Indent lines based on how many loops have been run
                if($Iteration -gt 0){
                    1..$Iteration | foreach {
                    $PropertyName = "`t$PropertyName"
                    }
                }
                #Show PropertyName
                write-host $PropertyName
                #Drill down recursively
                Map-NestedPSObj $rootProperty.value $NextIteration
            }
        }
        #Run if passed obj is an array
        "Object[]" {
            #Get Property Name
            $PropertyName = ($Obj | Get-Member | Where-Object { $_.MemberType -eq "NoteProperty" }).Name
            #Indent PropertyName
            if($Iteration -gt 0){
                1..$Iteration | foreach {
                $PropertyName = "`t$PropertyName"
                }
            }
            #Output PropertyName
            Write-Host $PropertyName
            #Drill down recursively
            Map-NestedPSObj $Obj.$PropertyName $NextIteration
        }
        }
    }
}

Map-NestedPSObj $TestObj
```

When I run this I should get the following output:

```
destination_addresses
origin_addresses
rows
    elements
        distance
            text
            value
        duration
            text
            value
        status
status
```

But instead I get this:

```
destination_addresses
    
Map-NestedPSObj : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Obj' because it is null.
At line:80 char:29
+             Map-NestedPSObj $Obj.$PropertyName $NextIteration
+                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Map-NestedPSObj], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Map-NestedPSObj
 
origin_addresses
    
Map-NestedPSObj : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Obj' because it is null.
At line:80 char:29
+             Map-NestedPSObj $Obj.$PropertyName $NextIteration
+                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Map-NestedPSObj], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Map-NestedPSObj
 
rows
    elements
Map-NestedPSObj : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Obj' because it is null.
At line:80 char:29
+             Map-NestedPSObj $Obj.$PropertyName $NextIteration
+                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Map-NestedPSObj], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Map-NestedPSObj
 
status
```

I do plan on eventually trying to add type data for each level, but for now I would be fine with just getting the expected output! Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? Been banging my head against the wall on this for several hours now, any help is much appreciated.

*Edit
For those stumbling on this in the future, there is a MUCH more elegant function posted below by Sage Pourpre that does everything I was attempting with this formula and more. However, the answer to the question I asked was to change:

```
Map-NestedPSObj $rootProperty.value $NextIteration
```

to:

```
Map-NestedPSObj $($rootProperty.value) $NextIteration
```

Answer was provided by /u/jducktape on r/powershell

Comment: `Set-StrictMode` is your friend. It will tell you where you're going wrong.

Comment: It appears as though you are not familiar with the debugging of a Powershell script. I recommend that you look into how to set breakpoints so you can debug your scripts more easily. It will save you a lot of hours. The first instance of your error happen in the `object[]` segment when looking at `Philadelphia, PA, USA`.  You do `$PropertyName = ($Obj | Get-Member | Where-Object { $_.MemberType -eq "NoteProperty" }).Name` ... There is no NoteProperty for that item thus it return `$null` but you attempt to get the name `.name` anyway, which throw the error.

Comment: Also, this `$PropertyName = "`t$PropertyName"` can't be good...  You're adding a number of indent and later on you are calling `Map-NestedPSObj $Obj.$PropertyName ` ... This mean you are essentially looking for a property name with a bunch of tabs in front of it (eg: '       PropertyName'  instead of 'PropertyName').  You're better off creating another property to hold the display value (property name with indent) so that the `Write-Host`  can use that while the `Map-NestedObject` can use the property name without the added tabs.

Comment: I 100% see the issue with that $PropertyName variable now, but for some reason it seemed to work 99% of the time which is why I missed it. I do use breakpoints, and was seeing the null issue but was going to tackle that next :) I will look into Set-StrictMode, it looks useful. I've just been picking up PS as I go as a way to make my job easier at work, so there are a lot of gaps in my knowledge. Thank you both for your help! I may keep tinkering with the above script a bit just for learning, but I think I'll actually use the amazing script by Sage Pourpre posted below.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your code, I can see several issues, which I already highlighted in the 2 comments I left to your question.

Here is a simple function I made while looking at yours to produce the desired result.

```
# Your json (compressed version) 
$TestJson = '{"destination_addresses":["Philadelphia, PA, USA","Montreal, QC, CANADA"],"origin_addresses":["New York, NY, USA"],"rows":[{"elements":[{"distance":{"text":"94.6 mi","value":152193},"duration":{"text":"1 hour 44 mins","value":6227},"status":"OK"}]}],"status":"OK"}'
$TestObj = ConvertFrom-Json $TestJson 

Function Show-Json {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param($InputObject, [Switch]$ShowValues, $Depth = 0)
    $IndentChar = "  " 
    #$IndentChar = "`t" # For me "`t" was too much indent
    switch ($InputObject) {
        { $_ -is [pscustomobject] } {
            $Properties = Get-Member -InputObject $_ -MemberType NoteProperty  
            Foreach ($P in $Properties.Name) {
                Write-Host ($IndentChar * $Depth + $P)
                Show-Json -InputObject $InputObject.$P -Depth ($Depth + 1) -ShowValues:$ShowValues
            }
            break
        }
        Default {
            if ($ShowValues) { Write-Host ($IndentChar * $Depth + $_) }
        }
    }

}
```

**No values**

```
Show-json $TestObj
```

**Output**

```
destination_addresses
origin_addresses
rows
  elements
    distance
      text
      value
    duration
      text
      value
    status
status
```

**With values**

```
Show-Json -InputObject $TestObj -ShowValues
```

**Output**

```
destination_addresses
  Philadelphia, PA, USA
  Montreal, QC, CANADA
origin_addresses
  New York, NY, USA
rows
  elements
    distance
      text
        94.6 mi
      value
        152193
    duration
      text
        1 hour 44 mins
      value
        6227
    status
      OK
status
  OK
```

**Bonus tip**

Instead of:

```
if($Iteration -gt 0){
    1..$Iteration | foreach {
    $PropertyName = "`t$PropertyName"
    }
}
```

To do the indent, you can use multiply on a string and replace your whole thing by:

```
"`t" * 5 + $PropertyName`
```

or (same but ditching the string concatenation `+` for a subexpression

```
"$("`t" * 5)$PropertyName"`
```

In both case, you don't need the `if` anymore since multiplying a string by 0 will give you an empty string.

Comment: Nicely done, you could leverage `$PSBoundParameters` but might be just a personal preference: `$PSBoundParameters['InputObject'] = $InputObject.$P` and `$PSBoundParameters['Depth'] = $Depth + 1` then `Show-Json @PSBoundParameters`.

Comment: That is amazing, but also slightly frustrating. Your formula is so much more elegant than what I was creating. Thank you! There's a lot to unpack/research here for future use...

Comment: @user13081745 Hahaha... Thanks. I edited my answer and added a bonus tip for you regarding the indent. If the answer is satisfying to you, don't forget to mark it as accepted ;)

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Noted. In this particular case, It saves me 2 long lines in exchange for having to pass down `-ShowValues:$ShowValues` like that but I concede there are some applications where it would be better, more practical (or even mandatory) to use `$PsBoundParameters`